# Lebesgue Measure of $\mathbb{R} \times \{0\}$

Tags: general-topology, lebesgue-measure

I know this is probably obvious, and I know the answer is that it is (Lebesgue) measure zero, but I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around it. Looking for an intuitive explanation.

Question: What is the measure of: $\mathbb{R} \times \{0\}$, where $\times$ is the Cartesian product.

---

Comment: With respect to what space, with which dimensional Lebesgue measure? $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: @Chappers I was looking for $\mathbb{R}^1$, but the answers below generalize to any $\mathbb{R}^n$, right? Since $\mathbb{R}^n \times \{0\} = \mathbb{R} \times ... \times \mathbb{R} \times \{0\}$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$m(\mathbb{R}\times\{0\})=m\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty[-n,n]\times\{0\}\right)\leq\sum_{n=1}^\infty m([-n,n]\times \{0\})=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (2n)\cdot 0=0.$$

**Intuitive explanation:** A line has no area.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\lambda$ denote the Lebesgue measure. Then since $\mathbb{R}$ and $\{ 0\}$ are measurable sets, if $\mu=\lambda \times \lambda$ is the product measure
$$
\mu(\mathbb{R} \times \{0\})= \lambda(\mathbb{R})\cdot\lambda(\{0\})=\infty \cdot 0 = 0
$$

Comment: It does worth to denote that in measure theory we  set $\infty \cdot 0=0$

Comment: @M.O. You are right It does! Let me edit.

Answer (score 0):

Take the rectangles $[n,n+1]\times[-\varepsilon/2^{|n|},\varepsilon/2^{|n|}]$ for $n\in\mathbb Z$ and fixed $\varepsilon>0$. Then their area is $2\varepsilon/2^n$, and $\mathbb R\times\{0\}$ is contained in the union of all these rectangles. Summing up the areas gives $6\varepsilon$, so the (two)-dimensional Lebesgue measure of $\mathbb R\times\{0\}$ must be $\leq 6\varepsilon$. Since $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary, the result follows.